# PHP verify array elements are all empty

Tags: php, arrays

I need to ensure that all the elements in my array are empty strings to process an action. The way I am currently doing it is incrementing a variable each time an element is an empty string. Then I check the value of that variable against a certain requirement N. If N is met, the action is processed. Below is the snippet of the code that checks for empty strings. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it and think there has to be a better way to do it because basically I am hard coding that value N. Can anybody else suggest another approach?

```
function checkErrorArray($ers) {
    $err_count = 0;
    foreach ($ers as &$value) {
        if ($value == '') {
            $err_count++;
        }
    }
    return $err_count;
}
```

Comment: Well as you already say it works, the only thing is that you could write it differently like just: `return array_count_values($ers)[""];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you do:

```
function areAllEmpty($ers) {
    foreach ($ers as &$value) {
        //if a value is not empty, we return false and no need to continue iterating thru the array
        if (!empty($value)) return false;
    }
    //if got so far, then all must be empty
    return true;
}
```

It will not have to run through the whole array if a non-empty value is found.

You could also do a shorter version:

```
function areAllEmpty($ers) {
        $errs_str = implode('', $ers);//join all items into 1 string
        return empty($errs_str);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just filter it and if it is empty then `!` will return `true` if not empty it will return `false`:

```
return !array_filter($ers);
```

Or if you actually need the count of empty elements then:

```
return count(array_diff($ers, array_filter($ers)));
```